# Azure Data Lake: How to compress and download a folder

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I've been working with Azure Data Lake, uploading and downloading files, but now I've been requested to download a complete folder (as a zip or any compressed format), I didn't find a way to do it with SDK.

Is there any way to compress a folder to download it?

Best regards

Comment: You would need to do it the other way around - download the folder and compress it.

Comment: @GauravMantri yes, but how can I do it in C# and keeping the folder structure in the compressed file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can only download the folder and then compress it, because there are no option to compress it before you download. Else, alternative to use [Azure Data Factory- Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview), where in the sink we can have to copy activity we can have the compressed version which supported by ADF- mentioned in the snip2- where in the sink you will have the option to choose from the Compression type along with Compression level.

**Snip 1 - where you can only download the files and folder from Azure Datalake**
.[image]

**Snip 2 -where I have used Copy Activity-ADF to copy files to Azure DataLake**
[image]

[Supported file formats and compression codecs by copy activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs)